# CSS style cliping text on first line and not shows all content on VueJS app

Tags: html, css, vue.js

My goal is show the text with 5 lines max to fit on the card and after that able to put a footer below that. I did make the style and it works at a file to test the code, but when I take it on my complete page then not works. The text is cliped on the first line.

[image]

```
<template>
  <div>
    <md-card>
      <md-toolbar :md-elevation="1">
        <span class="md-title">{{obra.nome}}</span>
      </md-toolbar>

      <md-card-content>
        <md-list>
          <md-list-item>
            <attr>
              Data início
              <attr-content>{{obra.dataInicio}}</attr-content>
            </attr>
          </md-list-item>
          <md-list-item>
            <attr>
              Área
              <attr-content>{{obra.area}} m2</attr-content>
            </attr>
          </md-list-item>
          <md-list-item>
            <attr>
              Dados gerais
              <attr-content>
                this text is not showed completely
                asdasdasdasd
                asdasdasdasddasdasda
                asdasdasd
              </attr-content>
            </attr>
          </md-list-item>
        </md-list>
      </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "CardObra",
  props: {
    obra: Object
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.md-card {
  width: 320px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 16px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.md-list {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.md-card-content {
  padding: 0px;
}

attr {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  color: gray;
}

attr-content {
  margin-top: 3px;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;

  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the parent of text add this

```css
div {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This will make sentence break if there is no more space left for next word and it will go to new line. You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)

Comment: I did it but not works. Also tried add on the `md-list-item` and `attr` styles and not works too.